# Finding Returning Customers based on criteria that will now be changed

Tags: sql

I’m trying to write a query that pulls data based on an original visit for all customers with code=A. I want to then see if any customers with Original Code A returned later. They may not be a Code A for subsequent visit.

```
Select name, visit_date, code
From Visit
Where code = A
```

How do I now look at only Code=A people, to see if they returned?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Do you just want the name, or all 3 columns?

Comment: "later", does that mean a later visit_date? Or can it be the same visit_date?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get the order of the visits.  Then take the first visit and join back to the table where the `visit_date` occurs after the first `visit_date`.

```
;with visitOrder
as (
    Select name, visit_date, code, row_number() over (partition by name, code order by visit_date) rn
    From Visit 
    Where code='A'
    )
select *
from visitOrder vo
join visit v
    on vo.name = v.name
    and vo.visit_date < v.visit_date
    and vo.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work by using a self-join on the name  for visit table to itself.